# Варианты ответов | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

Если смотреть по картинке, то видно, что у меня стоит `and` и пользователь может написать **`1`** из
правильных ответов, 
но можно ли сделать так, чтобы человек мог ответить не одним штатом, а **`2-3`**?

```
print('Четвертый вопрос! Какой 1 из Штатов США омывается Мексиканским заливом?')
q4 = input('Введи ответ: ')

if q4 == 'Техас' and 'Луизана' and 'Миссисипи' and 'Алабама' and 'Флорида':
    print('Молодец! Идем дальше!')
    a = a + 1
else:
    print('Это сложный вопрос, не расстраивайся! Идем дальше!')
    a = a + 0
```

Comment: Макар, пожалуйста, предоставьте код обычным текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Ты же понимаешь, что ответ не может быть одновременно "Техас", "Луизиана" итд? Он будет или Техас или Луизиана или Флорида... А именно это ты пытаешься проверить, хоть и неправильно.

Comment: спасибо, я же говорю я новичок, и я не знал об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, откопал в своих архивах. Сдул так сказать пыль. Тут даже больше чем Вам нужно. Вариант с множеством ответов, тут решен путем добавления к списку возможных вариантов ответов, варианта "Все вышеперечисленные". С точки зрения `usability` тут даже удобнее, чем у Вас - пользователю не нужно писать варианты ответов (высока вероятность очепЯтки при вводе), он просто вводит цифру варианта ответа. В общем, берите и затачивайте под свои нужды :)
P.S За код извиняйте, мну не питонист:)

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os.path
import configparser

iniFileName = 'questions.ini'
scores = 0;
question_num = 1

if not os.path.isfile(iniFileName):
  print("File `" + iniFileName + "` not found")
  sys.exit(0)

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read( iniFileName )
sections = config.sections()

if not sections:
  print("File `" + iniFileName + "` is not INI-file")
  sys.exit(0)

#Читаем миз .ini-файла вопрос с указанным номерм и список ответов к нему
def load_question(qNum):
  result = False
  for section in sections:
    #Нашли вопрос с указанным номером
    if section == 'question'+str(qNum):
      #Читаем текст вопроса и ответы на него
      result = [('question', config[section]['question'])]
      i = 1
      key = 'answer'+str(i)
      answers = [];
      while key in config[section]:
        answers.append(config[section][key])
        i = i + 1
        key = 'answer'+str(i)
      result.append({'answers':answers})
      #Очков за правильный ответ
      result.append({'points': {'good':config[section]['gpoints'], 'bad':config[section]['bpoints']}})
  return result

#Читаем первый вопрос
question = load_question(question_num)
while question is not False:
  #Выводим текст вопроса
  print(question[0][1])
  # и варианты ответов на него
  cnt = 0;
  for k in question[1]['answers']:
    #запоминаем правильный ответ
    cnt = cnt + 1;
    if k[0] == '*':
     right_answer = cnt
     k=k[1:]
    #выводим текст варианта ответа
    print( str(cnt)+') '+k )
  #запрашиваем от пользователя его выбор
  answer=0
  while answer == 0:
    answer=input('Укажите номер ответа:')
    if not answer.isnumeric() or int(answer)<1 or int(answer)>cnt:
      print('Неверный номер варианта ответа!')
      answer=0
  if int(answer) == right_answer:
    print('Вы абсолютно правы!')
    #Начисляем очки
    scores=scores+int(question[2]['points']['good'])
  else:
    print('Увы, но это не правильный ответ :(')
    #Начисляем очки
    scores=scores+int(question[2]['points']['bad'])
  question_num = question_num + 1
  question = load_question(question_num)

print('ИГРА ОКОНЧЕНА!')
print('ВЫ ЗАРАБОТАЛИ ОЧКОВ: '+str(scores))
```

Содержимое `questions.ini`

```
#программа ищет по порядку question1, question2 и так до тех пор пока не сможет найти
#очереджной questionN, поэтому если у вас будет question1, а потом question3 то не
#удивляйтесь почему программа нашла только 1 вопрос :)
[question1]
#Текст вопроса
question = Какой из штатов США омывается Мексиканским заливом?
#Варианты ответов, каждый вариант долже начинатьс яна answer и после него номер
#программа ищет по порядку answer1, answer2 и так до тех пор пока не сможет найти
#очереджной answerN, поэтому если у вас будет answer1, а потом answer3 то не
#удивляйтесь почему программа нашла только 1 ответ :)
answer1 = Техас
answer2 = Луизиана
answer3 = Миссисипи
answer4 = Алабама
answer5 = Флорида
#в тексте ответа, звездочкой перед текстом помечаем правильный вариант ответа
#если будет несколько таких ответов со звездочкой вначале, то правильным будет считаться последний из них
answer6 = *Все перечисленные
#кол-во очков (целое число!) за правильный ответ
gpoints = 5
#кол-во очков (целое число!) за НЕправильный ответ
bpoints = -2

[question2]
question = Сколько штатов США расположены на побережье Мексиканского залива?
answer1 = 2
answer2 = 3
answer3 = 4
answer4 = *5
gpoints = 1
bpoints = 0

[question3]
question = Какая игрушка считается самой продаваемой игрушкой всех времен?
answer1 = Слинки (игрушка-пружина)
answer2 = Silly Putty (полимерный пластилин)
answer3 = Фрисби
answer4 = *Кубик Рубика
gpoints = 2
bpoints = -1
```

Результат

```
Какой из штатов США омывается Мексиканским заливом?
1) Техас
2) Луизиана
3) Миссисипи
4) Алабама
5) Флорида
6) Все перечисленные
Укажите номер ответа:6
Вы абсолютно правы!
Сколько штатов США расположены на побережье Мексиканского залива?
1) 2
2) 3
3) 4
4) 5
Укажите номер ответа:4
Вы абсолютно правы!
Какая игрушка считается самой продаваемой игрушкой всех времен?
1) Слинки (игрушка-пружина)
2) Silly Putty (полимерный пластилин)
3) Фрисби
4) Кубик Рубика
Укажите номер ответа:4
Вы абсолютно правы!
ИГРА ОКОНЧЕНА!
ВЫ ЗАРАБОТАЛИ ОЧКОВ: 8
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. учту

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import collections


questions = [
    'Вопрос 1',
    'Вопрос 2',
    'Вопрос 3',
    'Четвертый вопрос! \nКакой 1 из Штатов США омывается Мексиканским заливом?',
    'Вопрос 5',
]

answers = [
    ('ответ на первый вопрос',),
    ('1', '2'),
    ('12345',),
    ('Техас', 'Луизана', 'Миссисипи', 'Алабама', 'Флорида'),
    ('5',),
]

number_of_correct_answers = 0
for i, question in enumerate(questions):
    print(f'Вопрос #{i+1}! \n{question}')
    _question = input('Введи ответ (если правильных ответов несколько, введите их через запятую): \n')
    _question = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), _question.strip().split(','))) 
    
    if collections.Counter(_question) == collections.Counter(answers[i]): #_question in answers[i]:
        print('Молодец! Идем дальше!\n')
        number_of_correct_answers += 1
    else:
        print('Это сложный вопрос, не расстраивайся! Идем дальше!\n')

print(f'Всего вопросов: {len(questions)};  \nПравильных ответов: {number_of_correct_answers}.')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите запросить у пользователя несколько ответов, то вы можете считать их в строку, а затем разбить по разделителю методом [split()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html). Только учитывайте, что если вы запрашиваете у пользователя несколько вариантов, то ответ может быть частично правильным

```
print('Четвертый вопрос! Какой 1 из Штатов США омывается Мексиканским заливом?')
q4 = input('Введи несколько штатов через пробел: ')
a = 0
if {'Техас', 'Луизана','Миссисипи', 'Алабама','Флорида'} >= set(q4.split()):
    print('Молодец! Идем дальше!')
    a = a + 1
elif {'Техас', 'Луизана','Миссисипи', 'Алабама','Флорида'} & set(q4.split()):
    print('Почти получилось!')
    a = a + 0.5
else:
    print('Это сложный вопрос, не расстраивайся! Идем дальше!')
    a = a + 0
```

Для того чтобы искать пересечения и принадлежность одного списка к другому их лучше преобразовать во [множества](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/)